# Minor clerical error- tier 5 mobility visa

Tags: visas, uk, working-visas

I just finished my application, and thought I checked it over pretty well  submitted, and printed.

I just did another check to realize I entered my mother's year of birth wrong. It's certainly not 2017. Lol

How shall I proceed? Is it advisable to correct neatly with pen, straight line through? Perhaps include a cover letter just stating my clerical mistake? Do I just mention this to the ECO?

My appointment is in three days... Help!

Comment: For what country's visa are you applying for? A tag would be helpful.